# Width of nested tabularx environments

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to create a RPG "character sheet" using LaTeX. There is a madness of nested boxes, underlined whitespace etc. involved.

I started with a `\begin{tabularx{\textwidth}}{|X|X|X|}`, and tried to nest `tabular` and `tabularx` ennvironments in that, intending to use `\hrulefill` to get the underlines.

The problem is, I'd like to make the nested tables as wide as the enclosing table cell allows, but don't know how to get to that value. `0.33\textwidth` is only a rough guesstimate, and does not take into account cell padding and the like.

After looking at the `tabularx` documentation, I tried `\TX@cell@width`, but that gave me an error ("undefined control sequence").

Is there a way to get a value like `\cellwidth` or something, for the width definition of a nested `tabularx`? Or a package specialized for this kind of work? (I tried the MiKTeX package manager looking for something like it, but came up empty.)

**Edit:** Ups... forgot the MWE...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
{ \begin{tabularx}{\TX@col@width}{lX}  %% <-- this does *not* work...
Name: & \hrulefill\\
Race: & \hrulefill\\
Profession: & \hrulefill\\
\end{tabularx} } &
\Large\textbf{Character Sheet} &
Empty so far\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cellwidth{\TX@col@width}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
{\begin{tabularx}{\cellwidth}{lX}  %% <-- this does *not* work...
Name: & \hrulefill\\
Race: & \hrulefill\\
Profession: & \hrulefill\\
\end{tabularx}}&
\Large\textbf{Character Sheet} &
Empty so far\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

You can't use `@`-commands without protecting them between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`; it's best to do it beforehand. Note that the command is `\TX@col@width`.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

why do you need the cell width? `\hrulefill` already works:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
foo \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} \hrulefill &foo \hrulefill &foo \hrulefill
\end{tabularx}
```

However, in this case the columnwidth is `\dimexpr \textwidth/3-6\tabcolsep`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the MWE in the example. I think it makes it clearer what I want to do - having the underlines start at the same horizontal position. `\hrulefill` only fills space that is already there... but I was also asking about the general case.

Comment: `6\tabcolsep`? That cuts the lines rather short... I get correct-looking results with `3\tabcolsep`...?