# How to limit the width of a nested table?

Tags: tables

The inner table (that is the 'very long description') goes outside of the page limits:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{messageWithProperties}[1]
    {
      \noindent
      \tabularx{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}lX}
          \toprule
          \midrule
          header &
              $\left\{\tabular{>{\bfseries}l l >{\sffamily}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-12\tabcolsep-5\fboxsep-7.5cm\relax}}
                  \toprule
                  id & integer & desc \\
                  key & integer & desc \\
                  \bottomrule
              \endtabular\right\}$ \\[4ex]
          \midrule
          #1 &
              $\left\{\tabular{>{\bfseries}l l >{\sffamily}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-12\tabcolsep-5\fboxsep-7.5cm\relax}}
                  \toprule
    }
    {
                  \bottomrule
              \endtabular\right\}$ \\[4ex]
          \midrule
          \bottomrule
      \endtabularx
    }

\begin{messageWithProperties}{someVeryLongName}
    userId & string & desc \\
    propertyName & veryLongStringType & a very very long description of the field \\
\end{messageWithProperties}

\end{document}
```

How to force it to be inside?

It would be nice to limit its size to `\textwidth - \widthof{#1}` and also allow to fill all available space. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How did you arrive at the adjustment factor `7.5cm`? Incidentally, which page size do you use: A4, US Letter, or something else?

Comment: @Mico, it's from the http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177078/118353 answer. More tables become too thin or too wide if these values are changed. The page size is A4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `environ` for avoiding nesting `tabularx` in a clumsy way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,environ}

\newlength{\bracewidth}
\settowidth{\bracewidth}{$\left\{\vbox to 1in{}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$}

\newcommand{\innerMWP}[1]{%
  $\left\{\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\hsize-2\bracewidth}{ >{\bfseries}l l >{\sffamily}X }
  #1
  \end{tabularx}\right\}$%
}
\NewEnviron{messageWithProperties}[1]
  {\noindent
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}lX}
   \toprule
   \midrule
   header & \innerMWP{%
     \toprule
     id & integer & desc \\
     key & integer & desc \\
     \bottomrule
     }%
   \\[4ex]
   \midrule
   #1 & \innerMWP{\toprule\BODY\bottomrule} \\[4ex]
  \midrule
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{messageWithProperties}{someVeryLongName}
    userId & string & desc \\
    propertyName & veryLongStringType & a very very long description of the field \\
\end{messageWithProperties}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the useless braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,environ}

\newcommand{\innerMWP}[1]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{ >{\bfseries}l l >{\sffamily}X }
  #1
  \end{tabularx}%
}
\NewEnviron{messageWithProperties}[1]
  {\noindent
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}lX}
   \toprule\addlinespace
   header & \innerMWP{%
     \toprule
     id & integer & desc \\
     key & integer & desc \\
     \bottomrule
     }%
   \\\addlinespace
   \midrule
   \addlinespace
   #1 & \innerMWP{\toprule\BODY\bottomrule} \\
   \addlinespace
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{messageWithProperties}{someVeryLongName}
    userId & string & desc \\
    propertyName & veryLongStringType & a very very long description of the field \\
\end{messageWithProperties}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That additionally solves (hopefully; need to test on the whole doc) another problem: inability to compose the table from smaller commands. I've got a dozen of variations of the header and a structure, so had to copy-paste the `newenvironment` for each of them. P. S. braces are not useless.

Comment: Great! You have solved a couple of issues I was wondering: 1) how to find the width of the braces 2) how to nest a tabularx within the main tabularx (I tried but without success). Moreover I see that `\cellwidth` is not necessary because `\hsize` is equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is a suitable solution but I've found 
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30673/101651) the way to have the cell width and I've used this width to set the width of the nested table columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% These code lines are from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30673/101651
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cellwidth{\TX@col@width}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{messageWithProperties}[1]
    {
      \noindent
      \tabularx{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}lX}
          \toprule
          \midrule
          header &
              $\left\{\tabular{>{\bfseries}p{.24\cellwidth} p{.27\cellwidth} >{\sffamily}p{.34\cellwidth}}
                  \toprule
                  id & integer & desc \\
                  key & integer & desc \\
                  \bottomrule
              \endtabular\right\}$ \\[4ex]
          \midrule
          #1 &
              $\left\{\tabular{>{\bfseries}p{.24\cellwidth} p{.27\cellwidth} >{\sffamily}p{.34\cellwidth}}
                  \toprule
    }
    {
                  \bottomrule
              \endtabular\right\}$ \\[4ex]
          \midrule
          \bottomrule
      \endtabularx
    }

\begin{messageWithProperties}{someVeryLongName}
    userId & string & desc \\
    propertyName & veryLongStringType & a very very long description of the field \\
\end{messageWithProperties}

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = I've never done a nested table before, nor created a new environment, hence I've answered as an exercise.