# How to typeout dimexpr?

Tags: debugging, dimensions, dimension-expressions

I'd like to debug some width problems in the following code, but the `\typeout` prints commands instead of actual value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{messageWithProperties}[1]
    {
      \noindent
      \tabularx{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}lX}
          \toprule
          \midrule
          header &
              $\left\{\tabular{>{\bfseries}l l >{\sffamily}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-12\tabcolsep-5\fboxsep-7.5cm\relax}}
                  \toprule
                  id & integer & desc \\
                  key & integer & desc \\
                  \bottomrule
              \endtabular\right\}$ \\[4ex]
          \midrule
          #1 &
              $\left\{\tabular{>{\bfseries}l l >{\sffamily}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-12\tabcolsep-5\fboxsep-7.5cm\relax}}
                  \toprule
                  \typeout{Debug \dimexpr\textwidth-3\tabcolsep-5\fboxsep-7.5cm\relax}
    }
    {
                  \bottomrule
              \endtabular\right\}$ \\[4ex]
          \midrule
          \bottomrule
      \endtabularx
    }

\begin{messageWithProperties}{someVeryLongName}
    userId & string & desc \\
    propertyName & veryLongStringType & a very very long description of the field \\
\end{messageWithProperties}

\end{document}
```

(code is from the "[How to limit the width of a nested table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339834/118353)" question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a `\dimexpr` is like an anonymous dimen register and the same commands apply so `\the` will give its print form

```
\the\dimexpr\textwidth-3\tabcolsep-5\fboxsep-7.5cm\relax
```